# How can I retrieve the details from a user id from my database in firebase in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to setup a profile page in my project, and I am trying implement a function that when the user clicks the profile tab on the bottom, it will display the info that is stored on my project's database after being redirected to the profile page.

Here is the code for my profile page:

```
class User_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityUserBinding
    private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var uid : String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityUserBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        loadUserDetails()

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
       

        val LogoutBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.logoutBtn)
        LogoutBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@User_Activity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        //navbar redirection
        val addImg: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.navCreate)
        addImg.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@User_Activity, Slam_Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val gotoUser: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.navUser)
        gotoUser.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@User_Activity, User_Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val gotoHome: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.navHome)
        gotoHome.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@User_Activity, Homepage_Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

here is the function I am trying to implement:

```
private fun loadUserDetails() {
     //db ref to fetch user info
     val userRef = databaseReference.child(uid)

     userRef
         .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
             override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                 for (usersnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                     //Log.d("FirebaseData", "Snapshot: $snapshot")

                     val email = usersnapshot.child("email").value.toString()
                     val username = usersnapshot.child("username").value.toString()
                     val uid = usersnapshot.child("id").value.toString()

                     //Log.d("FirebaseData", "Email: $email, Username: $username, UID: $uid")

                     binding.profileUID.text = uid
                     binding.profileEmail.text = email
                     binding.profileUsername.text = username
                 }
             }

             override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                 Log.e("FirebaseError", "Error: $error")
             }
         })
 }
```

This is what my database looks like:

[image]

what happens now after clicking the profile tab on the nav bar is that it loops back to the sign in page and when you click the profile tab again, it crashes.

I have tried to do different codes, but I am still getting nothing, even after researching numerous articles. The output should be returning all the data from the current user id.

Comment: Answer below. In the future though, please include information about the crash in your question - as "it crashes" is hard to help with for most folks here. --- When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading data from `/Users/$userId`, so the `DataSnapshot` you get in your `onDataChange` will have the information for a single user.

But the code in your `onDataChange` loops over the child nodes of the data snapshot, as if it gets a list of results. That won't work, which probably explains the crash.

The solution is to remove the loop from your `onDataChange` implementation. Such a loop is only needed when you get a list of results, not when you directly get the snapshot of a single user node.

---

The second problem is the UID value that you use in:

```
val userRef = databaseReference.child(uid)
```

You initialize this `uid` as:

```
uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
```

But if we look at the screenshot of the database, the `-Nl0...` values you have in there do **not** seem to be UID values generated by Firebase Authentication, but rather are push IDs generated by calling the `push()` method of the Realtime Database.

So while you didn't share the code that **writes** the user info, it seems like it's something like this:

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(...);
```

If you want to use the UID to identity the user's node, you should not call `push()`, but do something similar to what you do in `loadUserDetails` to build like:

```
databaseReference.child(uid).setValue(...);
```

or

```
userRef.setValue(...);
```

Comment: It returns null on the profile page now instead of returning nothing. will try to find research some more and thank you for the comment sir!

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation of a second problem in your code.

Comment: Thank you sir! And yes I was actually using the push key since I thought that by pushing it, means that the key would be the same as the ones in authentication (which was horribly incorrect). I’ll redo everything from scratch, thank you again sir and God bless!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```kotlin
private fun loadUserDetails() {
    // Check if user is logged in
    val currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    if (currentUser == null) {
        // Redirect to login activity or handle unauthenticated user
        return
    }

    val userRef = databaseReference.child(currentUser.uid)
    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val email = snapshot.child("email").value.toString()
                val username = snapshot.child("username").value.toString()
                val uid = snapshot.child("id").value.toString()

                binding.profileUID.text = uid
                binding.profileEmail.text = email
                binding.profileUsername.text = username
            } else {
                // Handle case where user data does not exist
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("FirebaseError", "Error: $error")
            // Handle database error
        }
    })
}
```

I've just added a check if the user is logged in.
Then I used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` to fetch data once instead of listening for all data changes.

Comment: it still returned blank sir, but thank you for the comment!

Comment: I'm sorry @JohnVillamor I'll try it in other ways, and if I got something, I'll leave that solution here.